# For thermal mass flow measurement technologies is it necessary to measure gas pressure to determine volumetric flow rate?

Tags: measurements, flow, thermal-conductivity, instrument

Mass flow readings from thermal mass flow measurement technologies often provide output readings in volumetric units (e.g. standard liters per minute). Mathematically I can derive the volumetric flow rate by dividing the measured mass flow rate by the gas density.

But in my experience the thermal mass flow meters do not have a pressure sensor built into them. And without a pressure sensor you cannot know what the gas density is.

So how do these flow sensors accurately measure volumetric flow?

If sensor processing assumes density at ambient pressure and there is a resistive load downstream of the sensor, pressure and density increase and the density assumption will lead to an incorrect volumetric reading.

Is volumetric flow derived by another means that does not require pressure measurement?

Comment: I never had to work with the technology, but I believe that you are basically correct. A thermal mass flow meter is only useful as a volumetric flow meter if the pressure is either constant (which may be the case for many applications), or if the pressure is measured in addition to the mass flow. Volumetric flow is usually measured in other ways, e.g. by measuring the pressure difference between the inlet and the outlet of a tube using the Hagen-Poiseuille equation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation.